# Magento : Hide admin side menu “mobile” inside custom plugin

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-community, module

I had to hide Some menus in Admin side.

I refered MANY questions here on Stackoverflow , on other sites . BUT they simply say ,

Create a file called adminhtml.xml under /etc folder of your module:

BUT no one told what should be in module , will it have class , what should be in it????

Lets take it easy :

I hav all folders like ,controller,Model .. In folder local\MyCompanyName\WelcomeInsync NOW WHAT ?

I simply created adminhtml.xml in etc folder but NOTHING happened

I used following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <xmlconnect> <!-- <xmlconnect> to match adminhtml.xml file of Mage_XmlConnect module -->
            <depends>
                <module>HideMe</module> <!-- Fake dependance to hide tab -->
            </depends>
        </xmlconnect>
    </menu>
</config>
```

What should be done ? I have folders only blank ,just etc has files config.xml + adminhtml.xml.

I tried cache clearing Nothing Worked . Is there any magento EXPERT to answer ? THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice and simple this one you create a module with a config.xml file and this config.xml can simply have the following.

```
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <xmlconnect>
            <disabled>1</disabled>
        </xmlconnect>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

This will just disable the complete menu "Mobile"....I have no idea why Mobile has the node xmlconnect, but still this will work.

Comment: Hi I did it with Creating Another Admin user with less priviledges.Thanks though

Comment: Yeah that is also a very valid answer.